# Determining if a PDF File with Cloud File path is Password protected or Not (path starting with https:\\)

Tags: c#, .net, azure, nuget-package, cloud-storage

I am Using **DotNetZip** (from NuGet Package). This will normally work for a File path having ("@C:) but once if use the Cloud File Path like (https:) it is giving me **IBM437 error**.
I can use this package but need to introduce some encoding which is the other problem.

I tried using **SharpZipLib** (another NuGet Package) but couldn’t find any information on internet related to it for a Cloud File Path. (http:).

I also tried **Spire PDF** but it throws **File doesn't exist (Parameter 'fileName') error** for password protected PDF.

URL’s for NuGet Packages -
DotNetZip - https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/
SharpZipLib- https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpZipLib.NETStandard/

Please let me know if any more information is required.

Comment: Hi, how's going?Has your issue got resolved ?

Comment: Hi @StanleyGong, please check the below comment and let me know if you need anything to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to download the .pdf file as a local temp file and then check could open it without a password. Just try the C# console app below:

```
using Spire.Pdf;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace PDFtest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var passwordPDFURL = "https://stantest1016.blob.core.windows.net/static/testPass.pdf";
            var noPassWordPDFURL = "https://stantest1016.blob.core.windows.net/static/testNoPass.pdf";

            var tempFilePath = "d:/temp/temp.pdf";

            //download file as a temp pdf file
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadFile(passwordPDFURL, tempFilePath);
            try
            {
                PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(tempFilePath);
                Console.WriteLine("PDF has been opened successfully with no password");
            }
            catch (Exception e) {

                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            //remove temp file
            File.Delete(tempFilePath);
            
        }
    }
}
```

Test password protected .pdf Result:

[image]

Test no password protected .pdf Result:
[image]

Comment: Hi Stanley, Thank you for the answer. But is there any way without downloading or opening the PDF. This may be an overload to the current Logic App as it downloads a file and I need to see how this will affect the Logic App in UAT/Production environments. I also tried another method of opening the PDF using PDFReader. If it opens in try block then it is not password protected else it goes to catch block that means it is password protected. But both methods can take more processing time if PDF File is >10MB File. I need a method which can tell me directly without downloading or opening a PDF.